# (VBScript) Same thing like last time.But now it's the {ALT}

Tags: vbscript

This is just like my last problem.

But now,its the {ALT} key. I made a script that typed a specific log file  to show it to the user and then exit the program (a.k.a. Notepad) aftewrwards,but the {ALT} part for SendKeys doesn't work.Any alternatives? I searched the site for something similar,but nothing came close.

Here is the log code:

```
set shl = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
set shell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
shell.ShellExecute "notepad.exe",,"C:\Windows"
shl.sendkeys "L"
Wscript.sleep 50
shl.sendkeys "o"
Wscript.sleep 50
shl.sendkeys "g "
Wscript.sleep 50
shl.sendkeys "#1 "
Wscript.sleep 50
shl.sendkeys "f"
Wscript.sleep 50
shl.sendkeys "o"
Wscript.sleep 50
shl.sendkeys "r "
Wscript.sleep 50
shl.sendkeys "MailSender"
Wscript.sleep 1000
shl.sendkeys "{ENTER}"
shl.sendkeys "{ENTER}"
shl.sendkeys "F" 
Wscript.sleep 50
shl.sendkeys "i" 
Wscript.sleep 50
shl.sendkeys "r" 
Wscript.sleep 50
shl.sendkeys "s" 
Wscript.sleep 50
shl.sendkeys "t" 
Wscript.sleep 500
shl.sendkeys "{ENTER}"
Wscript.sleep 10
shl.sendkeys "F" 
Wscript.sleep 50
shl.sendkeys "a" 
Wscript.sleep 50
shl.sendkeys "i" 
Wscript.sleep 50
shl.sendkeys "l" 
Wscript.sleep 50
shl.sendkeys "e" 
Wscript.sleep 50
shl.sendkeys "d. " 
Wscript.sleep 1000 
shl.sendkeys "C" 
Wscript.sleep 50
shl.sendkeys "o" 
Wscript.sleep 50
shl.sendkeys "d" 
Wscript.sleep 50
shl.sendkeys "e" 
Wscript.sleep 50
shl.sendkeys " h" 
Wscript.sleep 50
shl.sendkeys "a" 
Wscript.sleep 50
shl.sendkeys "d " 
Wscript.sleep 50
shl.sendkeys "10 " 
Wscript.sleep 50
shl.sendkeys "b" 
Wscript.sleep 50
shl.sendkeys "u" 
Wscript.sleep 50
shl.sendkeys "g" 
Wscript.sleep 50
shl.sendkeys "s. " 
Wscript.sleep 1000
shl.sendkeys "{ENTER}"
shl.sendkeys "{ENTER}" 
Wscript.sleep 50
shl.sendkeys "Second" 
Wscript.sleep 1000
shl.sendkeys "{ENTER}"
shl.sendkeys "S" 
Wscript.sleep 50
shl.sendkeys "u" 
Wscript.sleep 50
shl.sendkeys "c" 
Wscript.sleep 50
shl.sendkeys "c" 
Wscript.sleep 50
shl.sendkeys "e" 
Wscript.sleep 50
shl.sendkeys "s" 
Wscript.sleep 50
shl.sendkeys "s! " 
Wscript.sleep 500
shl.sendkeys "B" 
Wscript.sleep 50
shl.sendkeys "u" 
Wscript.sleep 50
shl.sendkeys "g" 
Wscript.sleep 50
shl.sendkeys "s " 
Wscript.sleep 50
shl.sendkeys "h" 
Wscript.sleep 50
shl.sendkeys "a" 
Wscript.sleep 50
shl.sendkeys "v" 
Wscript.sleep 50
shl.sendkeys "e" 
Wscript.sleep 50
shl.sendkeys " b" 
Wscript.sleep 50
shl.sendkeys "e" 
Wscript.sleep 50
shl.sendkeys "e" 
Wscript.sleep 50
shl.sendkeys "n " 
Wscript.sleep 50
shl.sendkeys "f" 
Wscript.sleep 50
shl.sendkeys "i" 
Wscript.sleep 50
shl.sendkeys "x" 
Wscript.sleep 50
shl.sendkeys "ed." 
Wscript.sleep 3000
shl.sendkeys "{ENTER}"
shl.sendkeys "L" 
Wscript.sleep 50
shl.sendkeys "o" 
Wscript.sleep 50
shl.sendkeys "g " 
Wscript.sleep 50
shl.sendkeys "e" 
Wscript.sleep 50
shl.sendkeys "n" 
Wscript.sleep 50
shl.sendkeys "d." 
Wscript.sleep 1000
shl.sendkeys "{ALT}"
Wscript.sleep 100
shl.sendkeys "f"
Wscript.sleep 50
shl.sendkeys "x"
Wscript.sleep 50
shl.sendkeys "n"
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Ehem,I wasn't looking for C# or C++. VBScript,please.

Comment: On that page is the documentation for the send keys method including the supported parameters. You'll find the code for alt on there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>ALT</kbd> for VBS `SendKeys` under a WshShell is described [here: SendKeys Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83(v=vs.84).aspx)

`ALT` is the percentage `%` symbol.